# Deploy ASP.NET Core on IIS using exe

Tags: iis, asp.net-core

ASP.NET Core seems to package a Kestrel service inside a .exe file.

All the [instructions](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jun/06/Publishing-and-Running-ASPNET-Core-Applications-with-IIS) I've looked at for hosting ASP.NET Core apps in IIS seem to reference having an entry point (Main() method) inside a DLL.

How do I stage the .exe file such that IIS recognizes it?

I don't see that part of the publishing process, and I would think that would be a very common step seeing as that is the default output of ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 5):

We did this by adding the following to the web.config file.  Note the processPath attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath=".\MyDotNetCoreApp.exe" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

First create a AppPool with No Managed code:

[image]

Then create a Website in IIS, I set it to port 8888 (as the default website uses port 80) point it to the web publish directory:

[image]

The website uses the AppPool with no managed code:

[image]

In the Web.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\AdviserPaymentList.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Then browse to http://localhost:8888/Home, any problems look at the logs.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed your arguments references a .dll file whereas ASP.NET Core outputs an exe by default. Did you just change your project to a DLL? Is there a way to host an exe?

Comment: You don't actually answer the question about hosting the published _exe_-file :)